# Why would a SQL Server procedure run intermittently slow with identical input?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, sql-server-performance

I've got a multi-query stored procedure which has started running intermittently very much more slowly - from < 1s to 15-20s minimum, sometimes up to a minute.

Ordinarily I'd suspect this was a parameter sniffing issue causing an inappropriate execution plan. However, it's doing this with totally identical input and no other load on the server, and it's done the same on multiple machines, through the client application and SSMS, and on SQL Server 2017 and 2019. Nothing in its processing contains any random or time-sensitive code, so it should perform identical operations with identical input.

I've tried running the call in SSMS with the execution plan display on. There isn't an obvious subquery which is intermittently slowing down, it's more that the whole thing slows down as one. Activity monitor isn't showing any obvious long-running queries either.

What else should I be looking for as to why this procedure is sometimes running very much more slowly?

Comment: Your explanation for ruling out parameter sniffing doesn't convincingly rule it out to me. The check you need to be doing is whether the execution plans for slow and fast executions differ - not a load of circumstantial info

Comment: Do you have querystore enabled? This will provide the info needed to determine whether (a) the plans changed (b) it was doing more work (c) it was encountering an unusually high number of waits

Comment: Start here: [Monitoring performance by using the Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Lots of questions here: Have you checked the plan cache for multiple plans for this procedure? Are there blocking chains going on during slowdowns? Do you have async statistics update on or off? What are the wait statistics showing, both for this query and other queries? Is there any other query running at the same time? Is there any other application running on the server?

Comment: Did you also get it to run slowly when you were testing in SSMS? I expect not, because SSMS defaults to SET ARITHABORT ON unlike just about every client library. Because query plans are compiled and cached based on the hash of the query text, as well as the current @@OPTIONS, you could get an entirely different plan in SSMS than your application(s) even for the same parameter input(s). Have a read through [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS? Understanding Performance Mysteries](https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html).